# non-convex normal domain

Tags: real-analysis

> finding a normal domain that is not convex.

I thought of this: $\{(x,y) | 4<x^2 + y^2 < 9 , x,y > 0 \}$. I can see easily that this is not convex. However I have troubles showing that this is a normal domain, since I do not find a parametrization.

Does anybody see how to parametrize? Since I believe that if it is parametrizable then it is also normal. Please, do show me the right path.

Definition:

A domain $A\subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is a normal domain, if there are  piecewise continuously differentiable functions $\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2} : [c,d] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $\beta_{1}, \beta_{2} : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that : $ A=\{(x,y) | a < x < b, \beta_{1}(x) < y < \beta_{2}(x) \} = \{(x,y) | \alpha_{1}(y) < x < \alpha_{2} (y ) , c< y < d\}$

Comment: What is a normal domain?

Comment: I put the translation of the definition, Sorry for making you ask.

Comment: A slightly easier example: $x^2+y^2>1$, $0<x,y<1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\beta_1,\beta_2:]0,3[\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be defined by:
$$\beta_1(x):=\begin{cases} \sqrt{4-x^2} &\text{, if } 0<x\leq 2\\ 0 &\text{, if } 2\leq x<3\end{cases}$$
and:
$$\beta_2(x):= \sqrt{9-x^2}\; ;$$
then it is clear that your set:
$$\Omega:=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:\ x,y>0 \text{ and } 4<x^2+y^2<9\}$$
can be represented as:
$$\Omega=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:\ 0<x<3 \text{ and } \beta_1(x)<y<\beta_2(x)\}\; ,$$
thus $\Omega$ is a normal domain w.r.t. $x$.